# Application fails to bind service

Tags: android

I am trying to bind a service which is included in a Library project with the following lines:

```java
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("de.ring0", "de.ring0.ToolkitService");
bindService(i, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

The binding process fails with the debug output below. According to the Android developer documentation the options in the two manifest files should be correct.

### AndroidManifest.xml Library Project

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="de.ring0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application android:debuggable="true">
        <service android:name="de.ring0.ToolkitService" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### AndroidManifest.xml Main Project

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="de.ring0.example.tactilecompass"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".TactileCompassActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="de.ring0.ToolkitService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### Debug Log from emulator

```
W/ActivityManager(   59): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10036
W/ActivityManager(   59): Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{de.ring0/de.ring0.ToolkitService} from pid=2994, uid=10037 requires null
W/dalvikvm( 2994): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.ring0.example.tactilecompass/de.ring0.example.tactilecompass.TactileCompassActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { cmp=de.ring0/.ToolkitService }
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { cmp=de.ring0/.ToolkitService }
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:874)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at de.ring0.example.tactilecompass.TactileCompassActivity.onCreate(TactileCompassActivity.java:28)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2994):    ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(   59): Process de.ring0.example.tactilecompass has crashed too many times: killing!
W/ActivityManager(   59):   Force finishing activity de.ring0.example.tactilecompass/.TactileCompassActivity
I/Process (   59): Sending signal. PID: 2994 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I am not sure, but this may come from the fact your service does not belong to your application package. Try to rename `de.ring0.ToolkitService` to `de.ring0.example.tactilecompass.ToolkitService`. Let me know if this worked and if so i'll move that comment to an actual response (i'm sorry I cannot do that test right now, otherwise I would have gave you some more verified information).

Comment: No that doesn't work either and would defeat the purpose of my namespaces. I tested it and the same error appears.

Comment: I don't see, in that case. I'll try to have a deeper look later!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
new Intent(this, de.ring0.ToolkitService.class);
```

Comment: Instead of crashing with a SecurityException it now only reports: `W/ActivityManager(   59): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=de.ring0.example.tactilecompass/de.ring0.ToolkitService }: not found
` Even though the Service is definitely available and neither the eclipse IDE or the java compiler complains.

Comment: @lhw: It feels like what you are running does not have the manifest shown in your question, for whatever reason.

Comment: @CommonsWave You were right. I actually ran a different manifest which had a namespace typo. And I worked on this for 3 hours now. >.< Thanks anyway.